# Signature in preface

Tags: macros, rules

I would like to make a signature field in the preface which looks like this:

```
                           City(#1) \today



        ___________________           ______________________
              NAME (#2)                        NAME (#3)


                      __________________
                            NAME (#4)
```

I wold like it to be a `\newcommand` with 4 arguments..  The "city \today" and "NAME (#4) should be centered (textwidth) and NAME (#2) and NAME (#3) with some spacing to the margins..

my preface:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,b5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to use a `tabular` environment (change the lengths according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand\Signature[4]{\par\bigskip
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{.05\textwidth}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.4\textwidth}
      @{\hspace*{.1\textwidth}}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.4\textwidth}@{\hspace{.05\textwidth}}}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1, \today} \\[10ex]
  \rule{.4\textwidth}{0.4pt} & \rule{.4\textwidth}{0.4pt} \\
  #2 & #3 \\[10ex]
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\rule{.4\textwidth}{0.4pt}} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{#4}
\end{tabular}
\par
}
\begin{document}

\Signature{G\"ottingen}{David Hilbert}{Emmy Noether}{Hermann Minkowski}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: _Göettingen_, really? `;-)`

Comment: @doncherry: such an unforgivable mistake! Fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\sig#1{\vbox{\hsize=5.5cm
    \kern2cm\hrule\kern1ex
    \hbox to \hsize{\strut\hfil #1 \hfil}}}

\newcommand\signatures[4]{%
\hbox to \hsize{\hfil #1, \today\hfil}
\hbox to \hsize{\quad\sig{#2}\hfil\hfil\sig{#3}\quad}
\hbox to \hsize{\hfil\sig{#4}\hfil}}


\begin{document}
\signatures{St. Anford}{John Doe}{Jane Doe}{James Doe}
\end{document}
```

Each signature line is `5.5cm` long and you might want to change this in the definition of `\sig`. Likewise, each signature line provides `2cm` of vertical space for the actual signature. One `\quad` of space is left to the margins - you could use here anything like `\hskip1cm` as well.

[image: Signatures]