# Vertical spacing options in tables built under the tabularx package

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx

Goals:

- Add a space above and below the text line containing the Table 1's column headers.
- Add a space below the second hline.
- Add a space above the third hline.

The code below contains the original table (#1) along with several failed attempts (#2,#3,#4)to accomplish the above mentioned goals.

Additional details:

1. I am using `pdflatex` to render the `.tex` file
2. I am using the `tabularx` package.
3. I am using `xtable()` in R to build the `.tex` for these tables, but it's not necessary to answer the question with `xtable` options since I can edit the `.tex` after using R.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated. Suggestions?**

[image]

[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=sf,hypcap=false,format=hang,width=1\columnwidth]{caption}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Understanding Tables: Vertical Spacing}
\author{Brian}
\maketitle
This report is designed to be a quick resource for editing the vertical spacing in 'tabularx' tables. \\

\begin{table}[ht]
\captionof{table}{Original}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
  \hline
Type & Total & Mean & Median & Stdev & Min & Max \\
  \hline
Test1 & 490 &  15 &   8 &  24 &   1 & 115 \\
  Test2 & 52610 & 1697 & 1620 & 430 & 920 & 2850 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
\begin{table}[ht]
\captionof{table}{Spaceing stretched above and below ALL cells}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
  \hline
Type & Total & Mean & Median & Stdev & Min & Max \\
  \hline
Test1 & 490 &  15 &   8 &  24 &   1 & 115 \\
  Test2 & 52610 & 1697 & 1620 & 430 & 920 & 2850 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}}

\begin{table}[ht]
\captionof{table}{Spacing streched ABOVE header}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
  \hline
\rule{0pt}{4ex}Type & Total & Mean & Median & Stdev & Min & Max \\
  \hline
Test1 & 490 &  15 &   8 &  24 &   1 & 115 \\
  Test2 & 52610 & 1697 & 1620 & 430 & 920 & 2850 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[ht]
\captionof{table}{Spacing streched ABOVE ALL cells}
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{14pt}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
  \hline
Type & Total & Mean & Median & Stdev & Min & Max \\
  \hline
Test1 & 490 &  15 &   8 &  24 &   1 & 115 \\
  Test2 & 52610 & 1697 & 1620 & 430 & 920 & 2850 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Generic ways of padding columns/rows in LaTeX is provided in [Column and row padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764). I'm sure you'll be able to find your answer there.

Comment: Thanks but that resource was used in the question asked above. Here are some other related resources used: [1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50352/inserting-a-small-vertical-space-in-a-table), [2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50332/vertical-spacing-of-a-table-cell), [3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85585/vertical-aligning-text-and-vertical-height-of-rows-in-longtable-environment)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach here (in terms of horizontal rules) matches that of what is suggested by [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). Here's what I would use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=sf,hypcap=false,format=hang,width=\columnwidth]{caption}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Original}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}
    \hline
    Type & Total & Mean & Median & Stdev & Min & Max \\
    \hline
    Test1 & 490 &  15 &   8 &  24 &   1 & 115 \\
    Test2 & 52610 & 1697 & 1620 & 430 & 920 & 2850 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[ht]
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \caption{\texttt{booktabs} version}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l *{6}{r} }
    \toprule
    Type & Total & Mean & Median & Stdev & Min & Max \\
    \midrule
    Test1 & 490 &  15 &   8 &  24 &   1 & 115 \\
    Test2 & 52610 & 1697 & 1620 & 430 & 920 & 2850 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

`booktabs`' `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` inserts additional (white) rules to separate the text around these rules a little. This, together with the use of an increased `\arraystretch` seems sufficient to obtain a breathable result.

Comment: After reading your solution, I noticed that the [xtable documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/xtable.pdf) contains an optional argument to set `booktabs=True`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `cellspace` package, that defines *minimal* vertical spacing above and below cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`. If one uses the `siunitx` package which also uses the letter `S`, the prefix is replaced with the letter `C`:

```
%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=sf,hypcap=false,format=hang,width=1\columnwidth]{caption}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format =4.0,table-number-alignment = center}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Understanding Tables: Vertical Spacing}
\author{Brian}
\maketitle
This report is designed to be a quick resource for editing the vertical spacing in 'tabularx' tables. \\

\begin{table}[ht]
\captionof{table}{With \texttt{cellspace}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ClS[table-format=5.0]SSS[table-format=3.0]S[table-format=3.0] S}
  \toprule
Type & {Total} & {Mean} & {Median} & {Stdev} & {Min} & {Max} \\
  \midrule
Test1 & 490 & 15 & 8 & 24 & 1 & 115 \\
  Test2 & 52610 & 1697 & 1620 & 430 & 920 & 2850 \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]